# Xcode 4.5 doesn't find deprecated functions

Tags: xcode, warnings, deprecated

my problem is that i can't visualize deprecated warning in xcode 4.5. like viewDidUnload or presentModalViewController.
I checked the flag "Warn About Deprecated Functions" and is correct (YES).
I tried to create e new project and copies all files, but i get the same result.
I tried to building with two available compiler LLVM GCC4.2 and Apple LLVM 4.1
The strange thing is that other project has found all deprecated functions correctly.
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't find"?  Doesn't flag, or reports the function not found?

Comment: Doesn't report the list of warnings in the issue navigator of Xcode, and in the single standard editor also.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that these warnings are based on your deployment target. (And not the base SDK, which is what I expected.) This seems like a wise choice, since in order to get rid of the warnings, there's a good chance you'll need to use newer methods that didn't exist yet in the older SDK.

So if you want to make sure you're seeing every deprecation warning, select your target in the Targets list, and set the Deployment Target to the latest version. Do a build or choose Analyze from the Product menu, and you'll see all the warnings.

[image: Deployment Target setting in Xcode]

Comment: Yes, my deployment Target is 4.3. However I have not more concerned about this and I don't know what happened, but after three, four or more clean/build all, it has started to find deprecated warnings.

Comment: put deployment target to the latest clean/build to to find all the deprecated warnings